# Express serve 400 on regex path

Tags: javascript, regex, express

I am trying to serve a 400 on specific files in the `/assets` path which contain `.map`. Example: `/assets/foo-huh4hv45gvfcdfg.map.js`.

Here is what I had, but was not working, as I expected:

```
app.get('/assets\/.*map$/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(400).send()
})
```

I think my regexp could be incorrect?

Comment: Do you want to serve a js file or give info about a js file?

Comment: I want to respond with a 400 status and that is all.

Comment: What do you mean by the `/`? Should that match? (In that case you should escape them) Also why would you use an `$` (end of string) anchor when your example has an additional `.js`?

Comment: no the / should not match the only thing it should detect is `.map` in a file name. But a `.map` could be anywhere in the string, could be `main.js.map` `.main.map.js`

Comment: Hi @JBd, I think this is what you need `app.get('\/assets\/.*map.*')`. You could also check this [site](https://regex101.com/) out. :)

Comment: @HannahMay I have tried your solution, and according to regex tester it matches fine, however when going to `http://url.com/assets/main.js.map` a 400 response is not returned :(

Comment: @JBd This has something to do with the way **express.js** handles the regex. Try this: `/assets/[\\s\\S]{0,}map{0,}[\\s\\S]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and check for ".map":

```
\/assets\/.*(?=\.map).*
```

Comment: I have tried the following solution: 


    `app.get('\\/assets\\/.*(?=\\.map).*', (req, res) => {
      res.status(400).send()
    })`

 However when visiting url/assets/main.js.map and url/assets/main-fhguhufgdh.map.js it does not return a 400 as expected.

Comment: Does it help if you remove the double backslashes?
`'/assets/.*(?=\.map).*'`

Comment: Or maybe you can replace the `\.` with `[.]` like `'/assets/.*(?=[.]map).*'`

Answer (score 0):

You were not looking for .js files.  try

```
'/assets/.*map.js'
```

or try this to search for files containing map but ending with any set of non whitespace characters and possible whitespace before the End of Line (eol)

```
'/assets/.*map\S*'
```

Comment: I have tried the bottom solution. However when visiting http://url/assets/main.js.map and http://url/assets/main-fhguhufgdh.map.js it does not return a 400 as expected.

Comment: I've removed the eol and whitespace options, keep playing with it.